# scalars can only be used with projection in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

scalars can only be used with projection i am getting this error while using foreach.How can i resolved this error ? how can i use LIMIT within foreach ? please suggest some
thanks in advance..

**Edit (Tichdroma):** Copied code from comment

```
A = LOAD 'part-r-00000';
G = Group A by ($0,$2 );
Y = foreach G generate FLATTEN(group), FLATTEN($1);
sorted = order Y by $0 ASC, $1 DESC;
X = foreach Y {
  lim = LIMIT sorted 3;
  generate lim;
};
Dump x;
```

Comment: want to share the piece of code that produces this error?

Comment: yea sure              A = LOAD 'part-r-00000' ;

G = Group A by ($0,$2 );

Y = foreach G generate FLATTEN(group), FLATTEN($1);

sorted = order Y by $0 ASC, $1 DESC;
X = foreach Y
{
lim = LIMIT sorted 3 ;
generate lim ;
};

Dump x;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LIMIT](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#limit) is available in Pig 0.9 in the FOREACH [nested_op](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#foreach).

If you want the top N element of each group, you might want to try to iterate on each one and individually sort and limit them:

```
A = LOAD 'part-r-00000';
G = GROUP A by ($0, $2);
X = FOREACH G {
  sorted = ORDER A by $0 ASC, $1 DESC;
  lim = LIMIT sorted 3;
  GENERATE lim;
};
DUMP X;
```

Notice that [TOP](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#topx) can be efficient when you just have a column of comparable values (not in this case).