# Pig Order By Query

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, apache-pig

```
grunt> dump jn;

(k1,k4,10)
(k1,k5,15)
(k2,k4,9)
(k3,k4,16)

grunt> jn = group jn by $1;
grunt> dump jn;


(k4,{(k1,k4,10),(k2,k4,9),(k3,k4,16)})
(k5,{(k1,k5,15)})
```

Now, from here I want the following output :

```
(k4,{(k3,k4,16),(k1,k4,10)})
(k5,{(k1,k5,15)})
```

Bascially, I want to sort on the numbers : 10,9,16 and select the top 2 for every row.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108206/scalars-can-only-be-used-with-projection-in-pig) and you could use a [Nested FOREACH](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#foreach), e.g.:

```
A = LOAD 'data';
jn = group A by $1;
B = FOREACH jn {
  sorted = ORDER A by $2 ASC;
  lim = LIMIT sorted 2;
  GENERATE lim;
};
DUMP B;
```

Comment: You can also just use the TOP() function instead of the ORDER and LIMIT. Its in the piggybank for Pig < 0.8 and buildin in for >= 0.8

Comment: I have similar problem. 
I am using TOP() but in TOP(2) if input is {10,5,5,1,2} 
I expect my output to be {10,5,5}
but its {10,5} actually
How could I solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't the sorting order by DESC ? Because the top 2 are requested ?